Can you allow clicks through your custom keyboard onto the underlying app? Android Studio
I have a custom keyboard that i made in android studio that features a open/close button to make the keyboard longterm hidden/unhidden. While in the hidden state, i have a small button in the bottom right corner that opens the keyboard.
My issue is that the empty and transparent area to the left of the button is intercepting clicks to the underlying application. I want the transparent area to the left of the button to be click-throughable to the underlying app.
In the following screenshot, the outlined red area is the area that touchs are only being received on the keyboard and NOT on the underlying app. I would like someone to click on the Trending Searches area of this google app, or anything else being featured on some other app. Is this possible with Android Studio?
Keyboard screenshot
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_level_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <!-- This is the button in question -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toggle_keyboard"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="\u2328"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#40A9A9A9" />


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alphanumeric_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/numbers_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="10">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="0" />
    </GridLayout>

<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/letters_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="10">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_q"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="q"
        android:fontFamily="Comic Sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_w"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="W" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_e"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="E" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_r"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="R" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_t"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="T" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_y"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Y" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_u"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="U" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_i"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="I" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_o"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="O" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="P" />
    </GridLayout>

<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/letters_row_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="9">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_a"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_s"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="S" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_d"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="D" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_f"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="F" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_g"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="G" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_h"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="H" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_j"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="J" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_k"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="K" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_l"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="L" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- Third Row of Letters -->
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/letters_row_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="9">

<Button
                android:id="@+id/key_upper"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="\u21EA" 
                android:textSize="24sp" 
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_z"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Z" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_x"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="X" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_c"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_v"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="V" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_b"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_n"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="N" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/key_m"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="M" />

<Button
                android:id="@+id/key_backspace"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="\u232B" 
                android:textSize="24sp" 
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center" />

 
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Symbols Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/symbols_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!-- First Row of Symbols -->
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/symbols_row_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="10">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_exclamation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="!" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_at"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="@" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_hash"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="#" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_dollar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="$" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_percent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="%" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_ampersand"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="&amp;" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_asterisk"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="*" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_left_paren"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="(" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_right_paren"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text=")" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_underscore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="_" />
        </GridLayout>

        <!-- Second Row of Symbols -->
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/symbols_row_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="11">
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_plus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_minus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_equals"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="=" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_slash"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="/" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_backslash"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="\\\" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_colon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text=":" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_semicolon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text=";" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_quote"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="'" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_double_quote"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="&quot;" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/key_question"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="?" />

<Button
                android:id="@+id/key_backspace_symbols"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="\u232B" 
                android:textSize="24sp" 
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/space_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="7">
<!-- Toggle Button to switch between Letters and Symbols -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle_symbols"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="!&amp;%" />

<Button
                android:id="@+id/key_pound_extra"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="#" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/key_space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:text="Space" />

<Button
                android:id="@+id/key_minus_extra"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="-" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/key_enter"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="\u23CE"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center" />


</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

